Create image of existing windows installation to run on a VM
I am in the process of learning and using Linux as my daily driver to do all my tasks. Right now I am dual booting linux and Windows and the Windows installation has lots of configurations and files like conda envs, rust packages, etc. There is only one application I use for work that requires Windows and so I want to encapsulate my workflows on a vm using a QEMU-KVM instance on Linux. I pretty much want to do what both this and this posts talk about but FROM Linux. I don't really want to do a fresh installation of windows because i would loose all of my current configurations, so i was wondering if there is a way to "Encapsulate" a bare metal windows installation into a .iso or .vmdk file i could load into a hypervisor like QEMU.
I am running Debian Bookworm 12.8 and windows 23H2 on my PC.

Yes; It can; You would need a new license to activate the installation but you can create an image of a physical machine and run the image as a VM.

@Ramhound How? That's what I am asking.

VMWare has a tool which be run to create an VHDD. I would just use that tool.

@Ramhound thank you very much.
